# Куда вставить конструкцию Switch...case для загрузки разных layout списка?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, adapter

Хочу загружать разные layout для пунктов списка, в зависимости от того, что находится в ячейке БД, я так понимаю надо грузить через `switch/case`, перерыл инет, но так и не понял куда нужно данную конструкцию вставить
вот собственно сам код адаптера

```
    public class myAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int layout = R.layout.history_lv_adapter;


    public myAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_DATE));
        String labels = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_LABEL));

        TextView date_lv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_lv);
        TextView labels_lv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label_lv);

        date_lv.setText(date);
        labels_lv.setText(labels);
    }

      public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Пытался в `newView` вставить, но там отказывается совсем работать, в `bindView` тоже никакой реакции, в общем чего только не перепробовал уже. Пытаюсь третий день решить это, помогите пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вам нужно перегрузить метод `getViewTypeCount()`, который будет возвращать количество типов вьюшек (по умолчанию возвращается 1)

2) Далее организовать ветвление по `getItemViewType()` в `newView()`, чтобы загружать нужный лейаут

3) Далее в `bindView()` подгружать нужные данные (опять с ветвлением по `getItemViewType()`

**P.S.** Вообще лучше такие игры делать с `RecyclerView` - он лучше приспособлен для этого. [Возьмите эту инкарнацию](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) `RecyclerView` - она умеет работать поверх `Cursor`

Comment: под ветвлением Вы имеете ввиду конструкцию `switch/case` ?

Comment: Да, конечно - ветвление это `switch/if`

Comment: я вижу, что Вы очень хорошо разбираетесь в данных вещах. Вы не могли бы, как специалист, высказать свое мнение по поводу того, что же лучше использовать `ListView` или `RecyclerView` , или все дело в предпочтениях? мб есть какие то явные минусы  перевешивающие чашу весов в пользу одного из способов? я понимаю, что в программировании нет одного однозначно верного способа решения задачи, но хочется знать мнение знающего человека, я пока учусь и буду рад любой информации))

Comment: Если список простой, то `ListView`, если что-то более-менее сложное `RecyclerView` -  я лично почти всегда предпочитаю `RecyclerView`

Comment: Ваш случай тянет однозначно на `RecyclerView`, причем с глубокой кастомизацией типа: [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter)